# How to launch PowerShell (not a script) from the command line

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am new to PowerShell and am struggling with what I assume should be a simple operation—I am trying to launch a PowesShell window from the command line.

If I launch a command line instance and type either `powershell` or `start powershell`, I am getting a PowerShell instance within the command line interface, i.e. the typical black background with white text. What I would like is for the typical PowerShell interface to launch—blue background with white text? I am running Windows XP with PowerShell 2.0 installed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set the default console colors and fonts:

http://poshcode.org/2220
From Windows PowerShell Cookbook (O'Reilly)
by Lee Holmes (http://www.leeholmes.com/guide)

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

Push-Location
Set-Location HKCU:\Console
New-Item '.\%SystemRoot%_system32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe'
Set-Location '.\%SystemRoot%_system32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe'

New-ItemProperty . ColorTable00 -type DWORD -value 0x00562401
New-ItemProperty . ColorTable07 -type DWORD -value 0x00f0edee
New-ItemProperty . FaceName -type STRING -value "Lucida Console"
New-ItemProperty . FontFamily -type DWORD -value 0x00000036
New-ItemProperty . FontSize -type DWORD -value 0x000c0000
New-ItemProperty . FontWeight -type DWORD -value 0x00000190
New-ItemProperty . HistoryNoDup -type DWORD -value 0x00000000
New-ItemProperty . QuickEdit -type DWORD -value 0x00000001
New-ItemProperty . ScreenBufferSize -type DWORD -value 0x0bb80078
New-ItemProperty . WindowSize -type DWORD -value 0x00320078
Pop-Location
```

Answer (score 33):

If you go to `C:\Windows\system32\Windowspowershell\v1.0` (and `C:\Windows\syswow64\Windowspowershell\v1.0` on x64 machines) in Windows Explorer and double-click `powershell.exe` you will see that it opens PowerShell with a black background. The PowerShell console shows up as blue when opened from the start menu because the console properties for shortcuts to `powershell.exe` can be set independently from the default properties.

To set the default options, font, colors and layout, open a PowerShell console, type <kbd>Alt-Space</kbd>, and select the Defaults menu option.

Running `start powershell` from cmd.exe should start a new console with your default settings.

Answer (score 11):

The color and window sizing are defined by the shortcut LNK file. I think I found a way that will do what you need, try this:

```
explorer.exe "Windows PowerShell.lnk"
```

The LNK file is in the all user start menu which is located in different places depending whether your on XP or Windows 7. In 7 the LNK file is here:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Windows PowerShell
```

Comment: Awesome! If you right click and select properties you can see how the .lnk is storing all the properties.